# Installation of R libraries in the Conda environment

Tags: python, r, yaml, dockerfile, conda

I need to create a Conda environment and install dependencies (Python, R) in this environment. 
All libraries - Python and R - are installed well, as far as I see in logs. No errors or warnings.

But it looks like R dependencies from file `r_requirements.R` are not installed in the same environment (`myenvpython`).
When I build and use the Docker image, I can use the installed Python libraries in the envirnment, but loading of R libraries fails.
How can I fix it?

```
FROM conda/miniconda3

COPY code/ci_dependencies.yml /setup/
COPY code/r_requirements.R /setup/

# activate environment
ENV PATH /usr/local/envs/myenvpython/bin:$PATH

RUN apt-get update && \
      apt-get -y install sudo

# RUN useradd -m docker && echo "docker:docker" | chpasswd && adduser docker sudo

RUN conda update -n base -c defaults conda && \
    conda install python=3.7.5 && \
    conda env create -f /setup/ci_dependencies.yml && \
    /bin/bash -c "source activate myenvpython" && \
    az --version && \
    chmod -R 777 /usr/local/envs/myenvpython/lib/python3.7

RUN apt-get install -y libssl-dev libsasl2-dev
RUN Rscript /setup/r_requirements.R
```